# Multiple Meteor Applications on Single Nginx Server

Tags: deployment, nginx, meteor, server, meteor-up

I have nginx set up on my server, and I can get my meteor applications which are running on different ports to run in different 'folders.' Here is the configuration:

```
server {
  listen                *:80;

  server_name           meteor.example.com;

  access_log            /var/log/nginx/meteor.example.com.access.log;
  error_log             /var/log/nginx/meteor.example.com.error.log;

  location /app1 {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  }
  location /app2 {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  }
```

The problem is that when I try to navigate within either app, the folder part of the url gets rewritten.

For example, if I am at `meteor.example.com/app1`, and I try to navigate to the contact page, the url changes to `meteor.example.com/contact` instead of `meteor.example.com/app1/contact`.

In addition, when I go to `meteor.example.com/app1`, I get a 404 in my app, because the router seems to think that I am trying to navigate to a page called `app1` in my application.

I have set the `ROOT_URL` on app1 to http://meteor.example.com/app1, but that doesn't seem to fix this problem.

Again, I can access each app correctly by going to `meteor.example.com/[appname]`, but I get a 404 in the application because it thinks that `[appname]` is a page I am trying to navigate to.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

I am using `meteor up` as my deployment tool if that is useful information.

Comment: This gets a lot easier if you are willing to use a different subdomain for each app. Is that a possibility?

Comment: It seems to be an issue of localStorage according to this: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3078

Comment: Ok, so it looks like this might not be 100% possible yet. Running on different subdomains might be the only way for now. The answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13665802/how-to-control-where-meteor-runs) seems to suggest that it is possible, however.